# What is the meaning of “faute de quoi”?

Tags: sens

What does “faute de quoi” means? Could I translate it as “without which”? It's in this [text](http://www.aleteia.org/fr/international/contenu-agrege/mongolie-un-lama-momifie-par-le-jeune-enflamme-les-esprits-5910554132611072?page=2) under the *Face à la « claire lumière primordiale »* section.

Comment: Many (too many ???) examples here: http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/faute+de+quoi.html

Comment: It means `otherwise/else`. `If the buddhist had a high spiritual life[...] otherwise his consciouness will fade out  [...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Selon le wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faute_de_quoi) :

> Locution qui indique qu'en absence de réalisation d'une première proposition, la seconde s'appliquera.

Si le maître ne se réalise pas (avec la certitude spirituelle qui affirme que la mort n'est qu'une illusion, alors que la Conscience est une et hors du temps) n'atteint pas la Réalisation, alors il sera réincarné.

Comment: Ha oui, ca c'est un exemple hyper clair qui va bien aider à comprendre le concept !!